# Flutter - programmatically close application when init failed

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, exit

My app performs some checks inside `main()` function,  before `runApp( MyApp());`, most important is load app configuration from Firebase. If failed, there's no any way to run not configured app. So I want to show message box saying "app configuration load failed", then after user press OK, exit app.

What is preferred way to exit app in that case? I need it working on iOS and Android.

Comment: Apple's human interface guidelines state that an app should never exit programmatically as it gives the impression that the app has crashed. I would suggest a better approach would be to provide the error notification and a "retry" button.  If the user doesn't want to retry then they can exit your app themselves

Comment: Yes, I've heard about that, Apple interface guidelines are confusing in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you need UI, I would suggest still calling `runApp` but on a different widget:

```dart
if(success){
    runApp(MyApp());
} else {
   runApp(ErrorApp());
}
```

For closing a flutter app programmatically, the best way is using `SystemNavigator.pop()` but if that didn't work, you can try `exit(0)`.